# c# and sql Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have tried to find the syntax error into my sql statment but i couldnt i tried to add () and [] but its same nothing change so could please help me with this error as i am getting this error message: " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'. " next to : " ad.Fill(cdt);"

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");
        using (SqlConnection carcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))

            if (cookie != null)
            {
            string CarSqlST = @"SELECT [JobNum], [Dept], [PubDate], [EndDate], [Employer],[VacCountry], [VacState], [VacCity],
            [Jobtitle], [CompLogo], SUBSTRING([jobdesc],1,40) as jobdesc FROM [jobs] Where 1=1 and [VacCountry] = [@Location] ORDER BY [PubDate] DESC ";


                var Location = cookie.Value;

                string condition = "";

                if (filterstathpjob.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                    condition += " and State='" + filterstathpjob.SelectedValue + "'";
                }
                if (filterJobhpjob.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                    condition += " and City='" + filterJobhpjob.SelectedValue + "'";
                }

                DataTable cdt = new DataTable();
                carcon.Open();
                SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand();
                ccmd.Connection = carcon;
                ccmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                ccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location);
                //ccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATE", cat);
                ccmd.CommandText = CarSqlST + condition;
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
                ad.SelectCommand = ccmd;

                ad.Fill(cdt);
                Joblistview.DataSource = cdt;
                Joblistview.DataBind();

            }
```

the 2nd code is

```
 protected void FilterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");
        using (SqlConnection carcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                string sql = @"SELECT [JobNum], [Dept], [PubDate], [EndDate], [Employer],[VacCountry], [VacState], [VacCity],
            [Jobtitle], [CompLogo], SUBSTRING([jobdesc],1,40) as jobdesc FROM [jobs] 
            Where [VacCountry] = @Location AND
            (@State IS NULL OR VacState = @State) AND
            (@City IS NULL OR VacCity = @City)                
            ORDER BY [PubDate] DESC ";

                DataTable cdt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand(sql, carcon);
                var Location = cookie.Value;
                ccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location);
                ccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", filterstathpjob.SelectedValue);
                ccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", filterJobhpjob.SelectedValue);

                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(ccmd);
                ad.Fill(cdt);
                Joblistview.DataSource = cdt;
                Joblistview.DataBind();

            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through to see what your final query is, after the `condition +=` happens? I suspect this is a SQL Injection attack that you're running against yourself, and you just need to parameterize the `SelectedValue` options.

Comment: The first guess is that something is wrong with the selected values.  Can you edit your question and include the actual SQL query that has the problem?  Looking at the query usually clearly shows the issue.

Comment: Hello @Matthew Haugen  i have tried another solution to avoid the sql injection but is the same it doesn't work i have edit my post and i add the 2nd code that it doesn't work as well

Comment: Could you check what is  your final query before execution. Then execute the same query in sql window. It could be type conversion error. It can go away if you know your query is right. So either show us what is your final query or execute it in sql window.

Answer (score 4):

This line in your first snippet appears to be your problem:

```
ccmd.CommandText = CarSqlST + condition;
```

You're adding a condition at the end of your SQL statement, after you've already done an `ORDER BY`. Your condition needs to be added *before* the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hi @Landscape Penguin  thanks for your reply but could you please show me how i can added before Order BY please.

Comment: I suppose you could just concatenate it like so: 'come.CommandText = CarSqlST + condition + "ORDER BY [...]". Inline SQL really isn't an ideal solution, IMO, but that should at least resolve your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    string CarSqlST = @"SELECT [JobNum], [Dept], [PubDate], [EndDate], [Employer],[VacCountry], [VacState], [VacCity],
    [Jobtitle], [CompLogo], 
    SUBSTRING([jobdesc],1,40) 
    as jobdesc FROM [jobs] Where 1=1 and [VacCountry] = [@Location] ";

    ................


ccmd.CommandText = CarSqlST + condition+" ORDER BY [PubDate] DESC " ;
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
                ad.SelectCommand = ccmd;

                ad.Fill(cdt);
                Joblistview.DataSource = cdt;
                Joblistview.DataBind();

            }
```